# PHP: I want to make background picker that saves color into cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, save, background-color

I am new to PHP and i want to make color picker with buttons ([RED], [GREEN], [BLUE], etc.) that saves color into cookie, so when page reloads, the color stays.

I think i could save color as $variable and then it would be a lot easyer.

SORRY FOR MY BAD english

EDIT: PLS POST CODE. IT CAN BE ALSO IN JAVASCRIPT OR  PHP/AJAX or just tell me how to set current bgcolor into $variable and then i will save it into cookie...

Comment: Use javascript/jquery for this. PHP is server side, Javascript is client side.

Comment: As @GrumpyCrouton mentioned, JS is better. But if you still want to use PHP, then try using AJAX. Are you familiar with these approaches?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your
way arround here. Also I suggest you check how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples. 
These guidelines will help you get better answers in the future. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi Mate, AJAX is JavaScript

Comment: Forgot to clarify, AJAX will be a combination of JS and PHP, which can process your server side queries as well at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just send the data with the get/post.  Each time they use the page send the info in a loop till it changes.  I think this would be much easier.

Comment: Also would take more resources and be a pretty bad way to handle it

Comment: His logic is based on when the page reloads.  So this logic is triggered anyway.  All you are doing is passing some more information on an existing process.  I don't agree with your assessment on resources.  But everyone has their opinion on things.